# The Wild Bogeyman's Crossword

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-crosswords

Solve this cryptic crossword and find the common theme:

[image: puzzle]

1. The wild bogeyman dropped his bag in the bank (5)
2. God returned the small animals (4)
3. The insect stayed in the hospital and became a family member (6)
4. I'm in half a byte of a magazine (4)
5. Colors of the music (5)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The wild bogeyman dropped his bag in the bank (5)

> BOGEYMAN - dropped BAG = OEYMN, wild OEYMN = bank: **MONEY**.

God returned the small animals (4)

> GOD returned = DOG + small (S) = animal: **DOGS**.

The insect stayed in the hospital and became a family member (6)

> Thanks to @M Oehm for this parsing: The insect (MOTH) stayed in the hospital (ER) and became a family member = **MOTHER**.

I'm in half a byte of a magazine (4)

> IM in half a by(T__E) = a magazine: **TIME**.

Colors of the music (5)

> @Chris Cudmore has what I believe to be the correct parsing for this, colors = BLUES which also relates to music: **BLUES**.

Answer:

> ```
>           M 
>         D O G S
>           N
>   M O T H E R
>       I   Y
>       M
> B L U E S
> ```

I’m not at all sure about the theme here, because

> Thanks to @jafe (because I only knew one of these songs), all answers are songs by Pink Floyd!

Comment: Could the last one be Rot13(gbarf)?

Comment: Yes! I like this answer a lot, thanks @ChrisCudmore!

Comment: (You picked the wrong parent. The hospital is only one room of a hospital or a series thereof.)

Comment: Oh dear, I can't believe I missed the obvious insect (I was too clued in on ANT). Thanks, @MOehm!

Comment: Everything but the last one is right (though it does fit).

Comment: Is it close to the correct answer, @pirate?

Comment: Not really, it's more of a music style

Comment: Got it.  Rot13(oyhrf)

Comment: Nice one @ChrisCudmore!!!

Comment: All correct now, just need to find the theme

Comment: The theme is only in the answers.

Comment: They're all rot13(Fbatf ol Cvax Syblq) :)

Comment: Fantastic answer @jafe! I only knew one of those; it’s slightly after my usual listening era... thanks very much!